# Select fields in a matching array and parent with C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object that I need to get some fields from just the first one matched.  The key thing is "prices" will either be sorted in ascending or descending "base" order.  Find the first matching "base" and also make sure "availability.amount" qualifies, then finally return the "base", "priceTypeID" and "priceLevelID".  Here is short snippet of the code that doesn't give me what I need; basically, one result gives me 3 matches while another doesn't give me the "priceLevelID".

The criteria I have below should return "base"=4000, "priceTypeID"="45082" and "priceLevelID"="2650"

---

```
public class PriceInfo
{
    public class Availability
    {
        public int amount { get; set; }
    }

    public class Price
    {
        public int @base { get; set; }
        public string priceTypeID { get; set; }
    }

    public class PriceLevel
    {
        public string priceLevelID { get; set; }
        public Availability availability { get; set; }
        public List<Price> prices { get; set; }
    }

    public class ZonePrice
    {
        public List<PriceLevel> priceLevels { get; set; }
    }

    public class OfferPrice
    {
        public List<ZonePrice> zonePrices { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<OfferPrice> offerPrices { get; set; }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = @"{
            ""offerPrices"": [
                {
                    ""zonePrices"": [
                        {
                            ""priceLevels"": [
                                {
                                    ""priceLevelID"": ""1653"",
                                    ""availability"": {
                                        ""amount"": 296
                                    },
                                    ""prices"": [
                                        {
                                            ""base"": 2000,
                                            ""priceTypeID"": ""45082""
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    ""priceLevelID"": ""1029"",
                                    ""availability"": {
                                        ""amount"": 300
                                    },
                                    ""prices"": [
                                        {
                                            ""base"": 3000,
                                            ""priceTypeID"": ""45082""
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    ""priceLevelID"": ""2650"",
                                    ""availability"": {
                                        ""amount"": 400
                                    },
                                    ""prices"": [
                                        {
                                            ""base"": 4000,
                                            ""priceTypeID"": ""45082""
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }";

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PriceInfo.RootObject>(json);

        var queryResult1 = obj.offerPrices[0].zonePrices[0].priceLevels.Where(w => w.availability.amount >= 2 &&
                                w.prices.OrderByDescending(o => o.@base).Any(w2 => w2.@base > 1000 && w2.@base < 300000)).FirstOrDefault();

        var queryResult2 = obj.offerPrices[0].zonePrices[0].priceLevels.Select(o => new { o.prices, o.priceLevelID, o.availability.amount }).
                                Select(o2 => o2.prices.OrderByDescending(o3 => o3).Where(w => w.@base > 1000 && w.@base < 300000).
                                Select(s => new { o2.priceLevelID, s.priceTypeID, s.@base, o2.amount }).First()).
                                Where(w2 => w2.amount > 2).First();
```

Comment: You're looking to select the *highest* base price? I'm not sure what you mean by "find the first matching 'base'", but your expected result is the one with the highest base.

Comment: It depends if the caller wants the lowest or highest price.  I edited the post and included the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you're asking for this:

```
    var query =
        from x in obj.offerPrices[0].zonePrices[0].priceLevels
        where x.availability.amount > 2
        from y in x.prices
        where y.@base > 1000
        where y.@base < 300000
        orderby y.@base descending
        select new { x.priceLevelID, y.priceTypeID, y.@base, x.availability.amount };
        
    var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

That gives me:

[image: result]

---

```
    var query =
        obj
            .offerPrices[0]
            .zonePrices[0]
            .priceLevels
            .Where(x => x.availability.amount > 2)
            .SelectMany(x =>
                x
                    .prices
                    .Where(y => y.@base > 1000)
                    .Where(y => y.@base < 300000)
                    .OrderByDescending(y => y.@base),
                (x, y) => new { x.priceLevelID, y.priceTypeID, y.@base, x.availability.amount });
```

Comment: wow, yes @Enigmativity, this is exactly what I was looking for!  Curious if this can be done in lambda expression; although the query format looks clean.

Comment: @KenLeung - I've added method syntax.

Comment: Note this will always take the first zone price in the offer price in the offer price array, and the first zone price array. That may or may not be what you're looking for (I also made an assumption in my answer that may or may not be what you need... not saying one assumption is better than the other).

Comment: @EricJ. - Yes, only because the OP did the same thing in their query. I assumed it was an artefact of the JSON file.

Comment: Yep, agreed. Just making it clear to the OP that the sample data might be misleading in their real-world scenario.

Comment: yes, points well taken.  I reduced the size of the sample data to help make it easier/less to read.  btw, @enigmativity, just fyi, the lambda expression produced a different result - it seems the OrderByDescending does not work?

Comment: @slabsken - Yes, it might need to be outside of the `SelectMany`. Can you try that and let me know if it is good now?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what your selection criteria are, but here's how I'd think about this query.

First, select the leaf nodes since you do your filtering based on them. Here, I make an assumption about ordering based on your example queries:

```
var ordered = obj.offerPrices
  .SelectMany(o => o.zonePrices)
  .SelectMany(z => z.priceLevels)
  .Select(l => new 
  {
    comparisonPrice = l.prices.MaxBy(p => p.@base).First(), // MaxBy from morelinq. Requires First() because there can be multiple equal base prices
    l.priceLevelID,
    l.availability
  })
  .OrderByDescending(l => l.comparisonPrice.@base);
```

Next, filter to results in the desired price range:

```
var minBase = 1000;
var maxBase = 300000;

var meetsPriceRange = ordered
    .Where(o => o.comparisonPrice.@base > minBase && 
                o.comparisonPrice.@base < maxBase);
```

Finally, ensure the required minimum availability and pick our winner:

```
var minAvailable = 2;
var meetsMinimumAmount = ordered
  .Where(o => o.availability.amount >= minAvailable)
  .Select(o => new {
    o.comparisonPrice.@base,
    o.comparisonPrice.priceTypeID,
    o.priceLevelID
  })
  .First();
```

Output:

```
base: 4000
priceTypeId: 45082
priceLevelID: 2650
```

Comment: thanks @eric j, i was thinking there was a way to do it in one pass but looks like that may not be possible.

Comment: Note, this is still in one pass. I split the query into separate pieces to make it easier to understand each part, but it's executed in one go. And if you wanted, you could combine the separate queries into one big one (that would run exactly the same way).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var basePriceItem = obj.offerPrices.SelectMany(o => o.zonePrices)
.SelectMany(z => z.priceLevels).SelectMany(s => s.prices).OrderByDescending(o => o.@base)
.FirstOrDefault(b => b.@base > 1000 && b.@base < 300000);

var item = obj.offerPrices.SelectMany(o => o.zonePrices)
.SelectMany(z => z.priceLevels)
.FirstOrDefault(o => o.prices.Any(p => p.priceTypeID == basePriceItem.priceTypeID && p.@base == basePriceItem.@base));
```

output

```
{
  "priceLevelID": "2650",
  "availability": {
    "amount": 400
  },
  "prices": [
    {
      "base": 4000,
      "priceTypeID": "45082"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thank you @serge, i was thinking there was a way to do it in one pass but looks like that may not be possible.

Comment: @KenLeung I can put it in one pass, but the expression  will be extremely complicated, I don't see any sense in it . I always think that a result is the most important, not the decorations around  the result.